# button click event not firing in asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, ajax

I am a humble student on a work placement, and I have inherited a 'semi-finished' app. It is written in C#(no experience at all) .NET(a little experience), using AJAX(no experience) and Jquery(little experience). I wrote a little method to grab text from a webpage and parse it into a text document. I want it to fire when the user pushes 'publish'.

The button won't fire. I have put  a breakpoint in my 'btnPublish_Click' handler, and it doesn't even reach it.

I've registered the button click event (I read that you needed to do this in C#):

```
namespace MaintainTenderFiles.ajax
{
    public partial class publish : TendersPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                loadPendingTenders();
                preloadTender();
                btnPublish.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnPublish_Click);
            }
            else
            {
               //more code
```

Then coded the click event:

```
    public void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String script = "alert('Clicked!!!');";
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.GetType(),
 "alertScript", script, true);
    }
```

All that happens when I click the button is it takes me to a page called 'published'.

Why can't I get the event to fire?

EDIT**

Apparently forgot to include the code for the button from the markup page:

```
 <asp:Button ID="btnPublish" OnClick="btnPublish_Click" 
  CssClass="ui-state-default ui-corner-all" runat="server" 
  Text="Publish" CausesValidation="False" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />
```

Comment: Writing javascript in the code behind is really not the best practice. the way classic webforms works makes me sick... :(

Comment: I'm just trying to get an alert to pop when I get the button click to finally work.... I will not have jscript in there.  What do you mean about classic webforms making you sick? What should I be doing differently? I am just learning, and am more than interested in best practices going forward.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with how webforms work. Once you understand the process it makes total sense. Also, there is nothing wrong with registering javscript on the codebehind when your doing ajax like this.

Comment: 1. Do you just want to execute some client-side code at `btnPublish` click ? 2. Does your markup file `.aspx` contain `btnPublish` button or you generate it dynamically in code behind `.aspx.cs` ?

Comment: When the button is clicked, the method grabs info from a populated form and then writes it to an html file, then pushes it into a folder waiting to be pushed to our external servers. I do have a button called btnPublish in my markup file, yes.

Comment: Try removing `UseSubmitBehavior="False"` from button's markup.

Comment: Still doesn't enter the click event...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the button event register so it registers every load.

```
namespace MaintainTenderFiles.ajax
{
    public partial class publish : TendersPage
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            btnPublish.Click += new EventHandler(this.btnPublish_Click);
            if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
            {
                loadPendingTenders();
                preloadTender();

            }
            else
            {
```

Comment: I still can't get into the click event.... Not only do I have the little alert box not popping up, it doesn't hit the break point I inserted....

Although I had it inside the first part of the if because the else part is a redirect, so I didn't think it mattered. But, as I said before, best practice... +1 for pointing it out...

Comment: You are doing a postback to the same page? Your form is runat server? Instead of assigning your onclick in the codebehind. Try setting it in the html like this  <asp:Button id="Button1" OnClick="Button1_Click" runat="server"/>

Comment: Also, I am not postingback to the same page. Although I have not implicitly stated, the way the original coder created this app, when this button is clicked it goes to the "Tenders/published.aspx" page. And funny enough, I can't figure out where he coded it to do such (and neither can my mentor).

Comment: There is your problem. You're assigning a click to a button that is never clicked. There are other ways around this and just forget about the click. You can either pass a query string parameter from the first page to the second or check Request.Form["controlname"] for post data.

Comment: Oh my....Pardon my ineptness, but what do you mean that the button is never clicked? I thought that I had created a button (ID btnPublish), and assigned a 'btnPublish_click' event. How is it never clicked? What am I missing? (Damn I'm feeling pretty silly right now....)

Comment: You said when the button is clicked it transfers to a different page. So its never doing the postback, its instead doing a post to the second page, which is where you should put your code. What does the form tag look like?

Comment: Oh, I see, so what you are saying is when the button is pushed, it goes to the new page BEFORE the click event occurs? So this is more of an 'order of operations' if you will?

Comment: Exactly, well except the server side click event wont ever happen on the first page when you post to a second page. The current page is never processed a second time because your instead moving to the second page. In order for the click event to occur it has to postback to itself. You cant bind a click event on the second page because the control doesn't exist there.

Comment: So awesome. Thank you for explaining it to me. Just to test the whole thing out, I posted back to the same page, and took out the else statement that redirects to a new page, and everything works. Thank you sooo much. THIS is precisely why I love this community so much. Even though the original suggestion wasn't what fixed it, you've got my vote...

Comment: If I have the information I want to retrieve incoded into a span tag (i.e.-<b>Title:</b> <span id='publish_title' />), is this info posted when my button is clicked? If so, how do you retrieve this info? If not, how can I make sure my info is posted so I can retrieve it at the next page?

Comment: The span text wont be available in the next page. If you want to use it on the second page just copy it into a textbox or hidden field with javascript before you post to the next page.